# select timestamps within ranges

Tags: sql-server, merge

I have got 2 tables. Example Table 1:

```
    ID        episode_id     episode_start      episode_end
    ----------------------------------------------------
    1             1            1                  2
    1             2            4                  5
    1             3            96                 105
    1             4            110                114 
    2             1            1                  4
    2             2            13                 24
```

Example Table 2

```
    ID        timestamp       Other_info   
    --------------------------------
    1             1            111                  
    1             2            142                
    1             3            114                
    1             4            112                
    1             5            116                
    1             6            123                 
    2             1            145                 
    2             2            156                
    2             3            154
```

I would like to merge the two tables based upon table2.timestamp = between table1.episode_start and  table1.episode_end.

The final table should be a subset of table 2 with only the timestamprows where there is an episode.

Question: **How to do this? What is the most computational efficient way?**

**EDIT:** In reallity my tables are much longer.

So, for example, the episode_start of ID = 1 be the same as the episode start of ID=1200 in episode 12. So simply merging them does not work.

**EDIT:** EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
    ID        timestamp       Other_info   
    --------------------------------
    1             1            111                  
    1             2            142                            
    1             4            112                
    1             5            116                              
    2             1            145                 
    2             2            156                
    2             3            154
```

and so on. The merge is basically some sort of filter of table 2 by table 1.

Comment: Add your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select table2.id, timestamp, other_info
from table1
left join table2 on table2.timestamp between table1.episode_start and table1.episode_end
where table2.id = table1.id
```

Output:

```
id         timestamp      Other_info
---------------------------------------
1              1              111
1              2              142
1              4              112
1              5              116
2              1              145
2              2              156
2              3              154
```

Comment: In reality table 1 and table 2 are much longer and there are more episodes with the same start and end time. So this does not work.

Comment: It works a lot better now! But now I an enormous number of duplicates! It seems like every row is duplicated by the max(episode_id) times per row. This makes it computationally dramatic.

Comment: i updated answer to use left join instead of case. In regards to duplicates i don't think i can help you without more information about the tables. I don't get duplicates from the provided tables using my query.

Comment: I found the mistake in the way I created one of my tables. Thanks for the help!